# systemd service to set virsh default storage pool

Tags: linux, centos, systemd, kickstart, virsh

I'm trying to run a script on system boot after an kickstart automated installation, the script just changes the default storage pool for KVM.
But for some reason the changes don't take effect, if I run the script manually or run `systemctl start pool.service` everything works fine and the default pool is set, but if I run `systemctl enable pool.service` via ks.cfg or manually after installation and then reboot, nothing changes.
I've tried setting pool.service to a few Types (normal, idle, etc...) but nothing seems to help.

I'm working on CentOS 7 x64.

ks.cfg

```
wget http://my_server/scripts/virsh/pool.service -O /etc/systemd/system/pool.service
wget http://my_server/scripts/virsh/pool -O /usr/bin/pool
chmod 755 /usr/bin/pool
systemctl enable pool.service
```

pool.service file

```
[Unit]
Description=Set default storage pool

[Service]
Type=idle
ExecStart=/usr/bin/pool

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

pool script file

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/virsh pool-start default
/usr/bin/virsh pool-destroy default
/usr/bin/virsh pool-delete default
/usr/bin/virsh pool-undefine default
mkdir /srv/virtual_machines
/usr/bin/virsh pool-define-as default --type dir --target /srv/virtual_machines
/usr/bin/virsh pool-build default
/usr/bin/virsh pool-start default
/usr/bin/virsh pool-autostart default

systemctl disable pool.service
```

Comment: Why don't you just do this in the kickstart?

Comment: I tried but after reboot the default pool doesn't change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `Type=idle` – it was added specifically for the login prompt, and is about as reliable as a dice roll. Just declare the dependencies explicitly. (For a short-running script, `Type=oneshot` is right.)

Your service communicates with libvirtd using `virsh`, meaning it can only work when libvirtd is already running. Therefore:

```
[Unit]
Requires=libvirtd.service
After=libvirtd.service
```

<sup>*(Adjust if your distribution calls the service differently.)*</sup>

Also, self-disabling services might not be the best idea. Instead, you could use:

```
[Unit]
ConditionPathExists=!/srv/virtual_machines
```

Comment: That worked great, I wanted to tried putting it in a loop but this method is way batter, thanks grawity